# Variable assignment not working correctly in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following queries:

```
SET @content_type = 'Movie';
select * from title where content_type_id=@content_type;
```

The above returns 0 results, however, if I do the following, it returns the correct number of restuls:

```
select * from title where content_type_id='Movie';
```

What am I doin wrong here?

Comment: I suspect an encoding issue.

Comment: What does `select @content_type;` return?

Comment: Are you typing these queries direct into mysql (or phpmyadmin or mysql workbench)?

Comment: Title is an odd name for a table though